# c - Avoid if in loop

Tags: c, loops, optimization, branch

### Context

Debian 64.
Core 2 duo.

Fiddling with a loop. I came with different variations of the same loop but I would like to avoid conditional branching if possible.

But, even if I think it will be difficult to beat.

#### I thought about SSE or bit shifting but still, it would require a jump (look at the computed goto below). Spoiler :  a computed jump doesn't seems to be the way to go.

The code is compiled without PGO. Because on this piece of code, it makes the code slower..

flags :
gcc -march=native -O3 -std=c11 test_comp.c

Unrolling the loop didn't help here..

63 in ascii is '?'.

The printf is here to force the code to execute. Nothing more.

### My need :

A logic to avoid the condition. I assume this as a challenge to make my holydays :)

### The code :

#### Test with the sentence. The character '?' is guaranteed to be there but at a random position.

hjkjhqsjhdjshnbcvvyzayuazeioufdhkjbvcxmlkdqijebdvyxjgqddsyduge?iorfe

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

/* This is quite slow. Average actually. 
 Executes in 369,041 cycles here (cachegrind) */
   for (int x = 0; x < 100; ++x){

        if (argv[1][x] == 63){
            printf("%d\n",x);
            break;
        }

    }


/* This is the slowest. 
 Executes in 370,385 cycles here (cachegrind) */
    register unsigned int i = 0;
    static void * restrict table[] = {&&keep,&&end};

keep:

    ++i;
    goto *table[(argv[1][i-1] == 63)];

end:
    printf("i = %d",i-1);


/* This is slower. Because of the calculation.. 
  Executes in 369,109 cycles here (cachegrind) */

    for (int x = 100; ; --x){

        if (argv[1][100 - x ] == 63){printf("%d\n",100-x);break;}


    }

    return 0;
}
```

### Question

Is there a way to make it faster, avoiding the branch maybe ? 
The branch miss is huge with 11.3% (cachegrind with --branch-sim=yes).

I cannot think it is the best one can achieve.

If some of you manage assembly with enough talent, please come in.

Comment: If you have printf in your loop, the timings are essentially meaningless.

Comment: Why are you using 63 directly instead of `'?'`? And is this actually a performance bottleneck in your system? I find it hard to believe that it is.

Comment: Also, it is likely that branch prediction will mostly amortise away the cost of the branch (at least for this particular dataset).

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves: for performance. avoiding promotion.

Comment: @Oli : 'printf..' read again please. It is not the absolute performance that matters here, but the relative.

Comment: @Larry That's just stupid. The type of `'?'` is actually `int`, there's no promotion. And even if there was, any decent compiler would perform the promotion at compile time. The only thing you get with 63 instead of `'?'` is uglier and unnecessarily harder to maintain code.

Comment: @Larry: I read it already.  Once you have printf, you're at the whim of huge number of slow, non-deterministic effects.  Relative *and* absolute performance numbers will not be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a buffer of well know size being able to hold the maximum amount of `char`s to test against, like

```
char buffer[100];
```

make it one byte larger

```
char buffer[100 + 1];
```

then fill it with the sequence to test against

```
read(fileno(stdin), buffer, 100);
```

and put your test-char `'?'` at the very end

```
buffer[100] = '?';
```

This allows you for a loop with only one test condition:

```
size_t i = 0;
while ('?' != buffer[i])
{
  ++i;
}

if (100 == i)
{
  /* test failed */
}
else
{
  /* test passed for i */  
}
```

All other optimisation leave to the compiler.

However I couldn't resist, so here's a possible approach to do micro optimisation

```
char buffer[100 + 1];

read(fileno(stdin), buffer, 100);
buffer[100] = '?';

char * p = buffer;
while ('?' != *p)
{
  ++p;
}

if ((p - buffer) == 100)
{
  /* test failed */
}
else
{
  /* test passed for (p - buffer) */  
}
```

Comment: It is a very good idea actually. I know '?' will happen so I can accept that way of doing things. Let me wait a bit after some other propositions to know if you are the accepted answer ;) By the way it is faster 368,940. I removed the buffer,read and last condition because I didn't need it.

Comment: Yes, if your test-character is guaranteed to be part of the test-sequence things are even more simple. @Larry

Comment: Yes, you do not need to add the test-char to end of the buffer.

Comment: it runs at the same speed here in the same conditions as my comment above.

Comment: Didn't I tell you: "*All other optimisation leave to the compiler.*" ;-) @Larry

Comment: You removed the `printf()`, didn't you?

Comment: #include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){



    size_t i = 0;
    char * p = argv[1];
    while ('?' != *p)
    {
      ++p;

    }

    printf("%d\n",i);


    return 0;
}

Comment: Otherwise it will do nothing : gcc will optimize